# killing background processes when script exists

Tags: bash, subprocess

I have scriptA which will execute another script which will startup in the background. Now I need to make sure that when I kill scriptA (cmd+c) that the background processes are also killed.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "This script is about to run another script."
  sh ../processes/processb/bin/startserver.sh &
 FOO_PID=$!
 echo "This script has just run another script." $FOO_PID
```

This script executes fine, but once I press cmd+c and do a 'ps' command on FOO_PID value , that process still exists. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE-----------

So I tried out below code, but still scriptC's process is not getting killed. I think it just only terminates scriptA ( parent) when pressed ctrl+c and therefore trap command does not get executed?

```
     #!/bin/bash

echo "This script is about to run another script."

   ../common/samples/bin/scriptC.sh &
 mypid=$!
kill -0 "$mypid" && echo "My process is still alive."

echo "This script has just run another script." $mypid

trap "kill $mypid && kill $$" INT
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a `trap` for `SIGINT`:

```
trap "kill $FOO_PID && kill $$" INT
```

or for any sort of exiting, handle the pseudo signal `EXIT`:

```
trap "kill $FOO_PID && kill $$" EXIT
```

Comment: Thanks heemayl, out of curiosity shouldn't it anyway be killed since I have not used 'nohup' here?

Comment: @user2894296 It's a long story. In a nutshell, the backgrounded process is now running in it's own process group, with the PID being the PGID.